# Set the size of UICollectionViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionViewCell which contains an image view and a label.

I am able to dynamically size the cell only when I have an image view.

I have added a label below the imageView with auto layout.

On viewDidLoad the image gets truncated or the text gets truncated. How can I dynamically size both the image view and label in the UICollectionViewCell.

Following is my code that works only with imageView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let imageSize = model.images[indexPath.row].size
        return imageSize
    }
```

I have an array of text and images from where I am displaying the content.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it may help you https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let imageSize = model.images[indexPath.row].size

        //find the height of label on setting text.
        //create a temp label
                let tempLabel = UILabel()
        tempLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        tempLabel.text = "abcd" //set ur cells text here
        let labelSize = tempLabel.intrinsicContentSize

        return CGSize(width: imageSize.width + labelSize.width, height: imageSize.height + labelSize.height)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

width of label = width of image view.
it is ok.
for height, you can use Intrinsic Content Size function to get size of label.

Answer (score 0):

**Here collectioncell is outlet of Collection view**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellsize = CGSize(width: (collectioncell.bounds.size.width/2) - 12, height:(collectioncell.bounds.size.height/3) - 20)

        return cellsize
    }
```